# Which gradle file to use to set the application as debuggable?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am newbie to android development. I have just started setting up my device to debug my application. while going through [android develop tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) it says to set `buildTypes` `debuggable` to true in build.gradle file . I am not sure which grade file to use gradle.build(Module) or gradle.build(project)?

Comment: It is the default value for the debug type.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two gradle files in your project -

1. Top level
2. App level

You need to add it to your app level gradle file -

```
YourApplicationRootFolder -> app -> build.gradle
```

You need to add it like this -

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Look at this image to get a better idea -

[image]

Comment: varun is this the same app module file?

Comment: I am adding an image file to my answer to give you a good idea.

Comment: Thanks got it. In android studio the top level is ( Project:MyAppName)  and the App level is (Module:app)

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 3):

Debug buildType makes build debuggable by default; instead, Release buildType makes build not debuggable by default. If you want to change this behaviour, you can define in your module app the property debuggable (boolean) as you need. [Gradle properties](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)