# Android Studio: Why is Release Build debuggable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.0

I've been trying for hours to generate a release build with Android Studio that is **not debuggable** so that I can upload it to Google Play. But sadly this is not working. When I try to upload the apk I get the following error:

```
You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play
```

This is not a duplicate. I have tried everything suggested in related questions...

**Update**

I have decoded the generated apk. The BuildConfig.class looks like this:

```
public final class BuildConfig
{
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.myapplication.packagename";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
  public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 2;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0.1";
}
```

So the build type is actually **release** and debug is set to **false**!

**But inside the AndroidManifest.xml, gradle has put**

```
<application android:debuggable="true"...
```

Debuggable is set to **true**! How come!?

Comment: Why not turn off both your `debuggable` as `false`... Perhaps the debbug version of flavor was trigger when you wanted to compile in release build. Then trace from there.

Comment: Did you have a separate signature for your release apk?

Comment: @Elye Thank you for your help! I much appreciate it. That's a good idea to tackle down the problem. I'm building the project with both debuggable turned off right now. I get back here after trying to upload it... No, I've used the same signature as for the last uploaded version.

Comment: All the best. Hopes you could hunt down the issue from there.

Comment: @Elye I feel like I'm getting crazy. I've uploaded the version with both debuggable set to false - it doesn't work either! Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you sign your release apk? Check SIGN in RELEASE mode in this post http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: It's also good to "Clean" your build first before compiling it again. Make sure the build output folder has no .apk.

Comment: @Elye First, I want to thank you for your help! I have made everything as described in the docs. I have a couple of other apps which I can export in release mode where everything works as expected! That's the unbelievable thing... I have also tried to clean/rebuild the project but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you have your AndroidManifest application set `android:debuggable="true"`? It's not needed there.

Comment: Perhaps you could remove your 'debuggable' variable in your release mode. Check this up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687046/which-gradle-file-to-use-to-set-the-application-as-debuggable, the release mode, doesn't even need the `debuggable` variable there.

Comment: @Elye Thank you for your patience! I could finally find the reason and solve the issue! The reason was that I had Library modules referenced which had an AndroidManifest.xml with `debuggable="true"` tag present. I have no idea why Android Studio chooses this "info" over the gradle settings... Anyway I'm very glad that it works now! Thank you a lot for your effort and have a nice day!

Comment: Which library is that? Perhaps you should tell the author about it. Glad that it works for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could finally find the reason and solve the issue!

The reason was that **I had library modules referenced which had an AndroidManifest.xml with debuggable="true" tag present. I have changed those to "false" and it works now!**

I have no idea why Android Studio chooses this "info" over the gradle settings... Anyway I'm very glad that it works now!